How to mirror a google.sites site with wget and convert links into local link references?
I am trying to mirror/download onto my PC a sites.google website I have using wget. I can get it to download no problems but when I click on index.html it starts with the local folder and then links straight back to the sites.google.
My site address is:

https://sites.google.com/view/craig-diana-wilkin/home

The wget comand I am using is:
wget --mirror --convert-links --page-requisites --no-parent -P documents/websites/ https://sites.google.com/view/craig-diana-wilkin/home

I have also tried:
wget --mirror --convert-links --no-clobber --no-parent --domains sites.google.com https://sites.google.com/view/craig-diana-wilkin/home

All of the above get me an index.html file but they all just hook back up the actual sites.google.com.

Which wget version? On what system?

$ man wget
...
   -k
   --convert-links
       After the download is complete, convert the  links  in  the
       document  to  make  them  suitable for local viewing.  This
       affects not only the visible hyperlinks, but  any  part  of
       the  document  that  links  to  external  content,  such as
       embedded images, links to style sheets, hyperlinks to  non-
       HTML content, etc.

       Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:
...

... in there are a lot more words about local[1] handling of files and whatnot. less is used to display man-page(s), there is a search option among other things you can do with it.
(hit h to see a terse version of all less's options)
[1] search for local !

Thanks Hannu, I am a bit lost here though, using the -k argument in the the string does not do what I need. It is still reverting back to the google.sites. Is there a way of converting the files that I have downloaded?

The -k option on the command line should cause links to be local-converted, check so that the other options doesn't put 'stoppers' to it. note also that wget respects the  robots.txt of a site - which might cause "trouble" in this regard.

Well as it turns out Sites,google solved the problem with their own system to down load sites so all is done and dusted. Cheers Wilky
